# Writing an array in JSON object in R

Tags: json, r, children

I have a dataframe where there are multiple cities. I need a separate json object for each state.

so the observation looks like the following:

```
name         country    state
Lake Forest             VT, CA, IL, NJ, NC
```

the object is

```
"location":[{
"name": "Lake Forest",
"state": "VT",
"country": ""},{
"name": "Lake Forest",
"state": "CA",
"country": ""},{
"name": "Lake Forest",
"state": "IL",
"country": ""},{
"name": "Lake Forest",
"state": "NJ",
"country": ""},{
"name": "Lake Forest",
"state": "NC",
"country": ""}]
```

some sample data (with the dput) is given below:

```
structure(list(name = c("Lake Forest", "Yale,UC Berkeley", "Harvard,Emory,the University of Denver,the University of Washington,Vassar College,Lake Forest,Texas Christian University", "MIT,Princeton,Yale,UCLA,NYU,Emory,UC Berkeley,UNC-Chapel Hill,American,the University of Washington,Lake Forest College,the University of Texas at Austin", "Princeton,Yale"), country = c("", "", "", "", ""), state = list(c("VT", "CA", "IL", "NJ", "NC"), character(0), character(0), character(0), c("CA", "CO", "CT", "FL", "GA", "IL", "IN", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MO", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NY", "NC", "OH", "OR", "PA", "RI", "TN", "TX", "VA", "WA"))), .Names = c("name", 
"country", "state"), row.names = c(3265L, 3755L, 3756L, 3757L, 3759L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Might help you:

There is a package `RJSONIO` which has **toJSON** - `Convert an R object to a string in Javascript Object Notation`

```
toJSON(x, container = isContainer(x, asIs, .level),
collapse = "\n", ..., .level = 1L,
.withNames = length(x) > 0 && length(names(x)) > 0, .na = "null",
.escapeEscapes = TRUE, pretty = FALSE, asIs = NA)
```

Comment: Select the Tic mark over the solution - to make this answer , if you find it helpful !!